# Difficulty with integrating with given css

Tags: jquery, css

A CSS has been provided to me ,i am trying to integrtae put my code in css .

This is the css

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Popcorn</h3>
    <div class="prd-items-detials">
        <ul>
            <li class="head">
                <form>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="checkbox-mini-0" data-mini="true">
                    <label for="checkbox-mini-0">Small Pack 150g</label>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li class="prd-items-qt">
                <div class="col">
                    <i class="minus"></i>
                    <i class="qt">12</i>
                    <i class="plus"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col">

                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    Rs: 150/-
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is the image how it looking .

[image]

I tried to achive the same using

```
activateUiHTML.append('<div data-role="collapsible">');
activateUiHTML.append('<div>Popcorn</div>');
activateUiHTML.append('<div class="prd-items-detials">');
activateUiHTML.append('<ul>');
activateUiHTML.append('<li class="head">');
activateUiHTML.append('<form>');
activateUiHTML.append('<input type="checkbox" name="Popcorn" id="Popcorn" data-mini="true">');
activateUiHTML.append('<label for="checkbox-mini-0">Popcorn</label>');
activateUiHTML.append('</form>');
activateUiHTML.append('</li>');
activateUiHTML.append('<li class="prd-items-qt">');
activateUiHTML.append('<div class="col">');
activateUiHTML.append('<i class="minus"></i>');
activateUiHTML.append('<i class="qt">12</i>');
activateUiHTML.append('<i class="plus"></i>');
activateUiHTML.append('</div>');
activateUiHTML.append('<div class="col">150</div>');
activateUiHTML.append('</li>');
activateUiHTML.append('</ul>');
activateUiHTML.append('</div>');
activateUiHTML.append('</div>');
activateUiHTML.append(activateUiHTML) ;
```

But it appears this way

[image]

Could anybody please let me know how to build that dynamically ??

Comment: First of all the first code isn't CSS, it's HTML. Second I don't really know what your problem is?

Comment: Specify what exactly the issue is

Comment: Seems like you want to build a list of items in that manner. If yes and if you are familiar with AngularJS, look at the ng-repeat directive using which you could have a template defined and it would replicate that template for the various items. You'd pass in the items as an array of objects. Difficult to assist further based on the limited information you have provided regarding what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: To make it look how you want, put the classes from the HTML in your CSS and duplicate the styles from the image you want to duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you append single `<div>` browser closes that automatically so it breaks your html.

If you really want to do it, you could create it like this:

```
activateUiHTML.append('<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>Popcorn</h3><div class="prd-items-detials"><ul><li class="head"><form><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="checkbox-mini-0" data-mini="true"><label for="checkbox-mini-0">Small Pack 150g</label></form></li><li class="prd-items-qt"><div class="col"><i class="minus"></i><i class="qt">12</i><i class="plus"></i></div><div class="col"></div><div class="col">Rs: 150/-</div></li></ul></div></div>');
```

You should think about using templates (ex. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jansav/Mnc3c/))